# Зачем visual studio 2017 создает собственную папку "program files (x86)"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

У меня установлена на виртуальной машине Windows 7 x32, после установки visual studio 2017 на эту виртуалку появилась новая папка "program files (x86)". Не могу понять зачем она если система x32?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Апгрейд или установку поверх 64-битной системы не делали?

Comment: На  VirtualBox установлена чистая оригинальная Windows 7 x32 и скаченная с оф сайта visual studio 2017, и больше на этой машине ничего нет!